# My result for matrix multiplication using verilog is not getting displayed

Tags: verilog, fpga, vivado

I'm getting my matrix multiplication output waveform in hexadecimal but not in matrix form as shown in

[image: this image link].

The Matrix answer (`Res1`) is given as {0,0},{0,0} whereas the expected answer would be {19,22},{43,50}.  Why do I get this unexpected answer?

// Main file

```
module mat_mul(A,B,Res);

input [31:0] A;
input [31:0] B;
output [31:0] Res;

//internal variables 

reg [31:0] Res;
reg [7:0] A1 [0:1][0:1];
reg [7:0] B1 [0:1][0:1];
reg [7:0] Res1 [0:1][0:1]; 
integer i,j,k;

always@ (A or B)
begin
//Initialize the matrices-convert 1 D to 3D arrays
    {A1[0][0],A1[0][1],A1[1][0],A1[1][1]} = A;
    {B1[0][0],B1[0][1],B1[1][0],B1[1][1]} = B;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    {Res1[0][0],Res1[0][1],Res1[1][0],Res1[1][1]} = 32'd0;

    //Matrix multiplication
    for(i=0;i < 2;i=i+1)
        for(j=0;j < 2;j=j+1)
            for(k=0;k < 2;k=k+1)
                Res1[i][j] = Res1[i][j] + (A1[i][k] * B1[k][j]);
    //final output assignment - 3D array to 1D array conversion.            
    Res = {Res1[0][0],Res1[0][1],Res1[1][0],Res1[1][1]};   

end 
endmodule
```

// Test Bench

```
module mat_mul_tb();

// Inputs
reg [31:0] A;
reg [31:0] B;
reg [7:0] A1[0:1][0:1];
reg [7:0] B1[0:1][0:1];

// Outputs
wire [31:0] Res;
reg [7:0] Res1[0:1][0:1];


// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
mat_mul uut (.A(A),.B(B),.Res(Res));

initial begin
    // Apply Inputs
    A = 0;  B = 0;  #100;
    A = {8'd1,8'd2,8'd3,8'd4};
    B = {8'd5,8'd6,8'd7,8'd8};

    {A1[0][0],A1[0][1],A1[1][0],A1[1][1]} = A;
    {B1[0][0],B1[0][1],B1[1][0],B1[1][1]} = B;
    {Res1[0][0],Res1[0][1],Res1[1][0],Res1[1][1]} = Res;

    $display(A1);
    $display(B1);
    $display(Res1);

end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a race condition between when Res1 is assigned and when you `$display` its value.  You should make sure  Res1 is updated whenever Res changes, and you can add a delay before displaying:

```
always @* {Res1[0][0],Res1[0][1],Res1[1][0],Res1[1][1]} = Res;

initial begin
    // Apply Inputs
    A = 0;  B = 0;  #100;
    A = {8'd1,8'd2,8'd3,8'd4};
    B = {8'd5,8'd6,8'd7,8'd8};

    {A1[0][0],A1[0][1],A1[1][0],A1[1][1]} = A;
    {B1[0][0],B1[0][1],B1[1][0],B1[1][1]} = B;
//    {Res1[0][0],Res1[0][1],Res1[1][0],Res1[1][1]} = Res;

    #1; // Add some delay
    $display(A1);
    $display(B1);
    $display(Res1);
end
```

The `@*` syntax means that every time the RHS of an assignment (`Res`) changes, the LHS (`Res1`) is updated. Refer to the free IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 9.4.2.2 *Implicit event_expression list*.